# Lambda function with UpdateRestApiCommand, how to update to work in version node 18

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I updated a lambda function to node 18, but there are changes to do with my `UpdateRestApiCommand`.

Here's the original that worked in the older version:

```js
    const request = apigateway.updateRestApi(params);
    request
      .on('success', function(response) {
        console.log("Success!");
        resolve(response.data);
      }).
      on('error', function(error, response) {
        console.log("Error!");
        reject(response.error);
      }).
      on('complete', function(response) {
        console.log("Done!");
      })
      .send()
  });
```

Here's my imports:

```js
const https = require("https");
const env = process.env.ENV;
const resource = process.env.RESOURCE;
const restApiId = process.env.REST_API_ID;
const ce_base_url = process.env.CE_BASE_URL;
const { APIGatewayClient, UpdateRestApiCommand  } = require("@aws-sdk/client-api-gateway");
const stage = process.env.STAGE;
```

And now I've found I need to use `UpdateRestApiCommand` I think so I've got this:

```js
    new  UpdateRestApiCommand(params)
      .on('success', function(response) {
        console.log("Success!");
        resolve(response.data);
      }).
      on('error', function(error, response) {
        console.log("Error!");
        reject(response.error);
      }).
      on('complete', function(response) {
        console.log("Done!");
      })
      .send()
  });
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "(intermediate value).on is not a function",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: (intermediate value).on is not a function",
        "    at /var/task/index.js:64:8",
        "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
        "    at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:36:25)",
        "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nodejs18.x` [runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-nodejs.html) has the [AWS JS SDK v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html) pre-installed. Earlier runtime versions came with v2.

Here's the [basic pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-api-gateway/index.html#getting-started) to use the v3 SDK clients in a Lambda handler:

```js
const client = new APIGatewayClient({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

export async function handler(event, context) {
  // ...

  const cmd = new UpdateRestApiCommand(params);

  const response = await client.send(cmd);
}
```